# ARM template for 2 nets in mutual peering

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I need to build a custom arm template that does the following:

- create virtual-network-1
- create virtual-network-2
- create peering from virtual-network-1 to virtual-network-2
- create peering from virtual-network-2 to virtual-network-1

I have created these resources manually, and generated the corresponding arm template, but when I try to run the template I receive a circular dependency error.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "virtualNetworks_vnet1_name": {
        "defaultValue": "vnet1",
        "type": "String"
    },
    "virtualNetworks_vnet2_name": {
        "defaultValue": "vnet2",
        "type": "String"
    }
},
"variables": {},
"resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet1_name')]",
        "location": "centralus",
        "dependsOn": [
        ],
        "properties": {
            "addressSpace": {
                "addressPrefixes": [
                    "10.1.0.0/16"
                ]
            },
            "enableDdosProtection": false
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet2_name')]",
        "location": "centralus",
        "dependsOn": [
        ],
        "properties": {
            "addressSpace": {
                "addressPrefixes": [
                    "10.2.0.0/16"
                ]
            },
            "enableDdosProtection": false
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet1_name'), '/default')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet1_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "addressPrefix": "10.1.0.0/24",
            "delegations": [],
            "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
            "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet2_name'), '/default')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet2_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "addressPrefix": "10.2.0.0/16",
            "delegations": [],
            "privateEndpointNetworkPolicies": "Enabled",
            "privateLinkServiceNetworkPolicies": "Enabled"
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet1_name'), '/peer1')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet1_name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet2_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "peeringState": "Connected",
            "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet2_name'))]"
            },
            "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
            "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
            "allowGatewayTransit": false,
            "useRemoteGateways": false,
            "remoteAddressSpace": {
                "addressPrefixes": [
                    "10.2.0.0/16"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/virtualNetworkPeerings",
        "apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet2_name'), '/peer2')]",
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet2_name'))]",
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet1_name'))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "peeringState": "Connected",
            "remoteVirtualNetwork": {
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworks_vnet1_name'))]"
            },
            "allowVirtualNetworkAccess": true,
            "allowForwardedTraffic": true,
            "allowGatewayTransit": false,
            "useRemoteGateways": false,
            "remoteAddressSpace": {
                "addressPrefixes": [
                    "10.1.0.0/16"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}